# Adding Firewall inbound blocking rule in a SF Cluster makes everything unavailable

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am using below PowerShell Script to add a rule to block certain IP:

```
Write-Host "Check if the outbound firewall rules exists , else create it." 

$firewallOutgoingRule  = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "BlockOutgoingMonitoring"

If ($firewallOutgoingRule -eq $null) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Outbound firewall rules does not exist so create it." 
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockOutgoingMonitoring  -Direction Outbound -Action Block -RemoteAddress /* Some Ips*/
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Outbound firewall rules already exist so continue." 
}

Write-Host "Check if the inbound firewall rules exists , else create it." 

$firewallIncomingRule  = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "BlockIncomingMonitoring"

If ($firewallIncomingRule -eq $null) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Inbound firewall rules does not exist so create it." 
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName BlockIncomingMonitoring  -Direction Inbound -Action Block -RemoteAddress /* Some Ips*/ 
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Inbound firewall rules already exist so continue." 
}
```

The issue I am having currently is that as soon I run this script as part of the set up called from `SetupEntryPoint`, the SF explorer looses connectivity to the Application and turns to page cannot be displayed. I am unable to access this application post the script execution.

I can share more details but anything that you see obviously wrong with the script or the approach.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to the Probing rules set up on the Load balancer for my node type. It was the same IP which we were trying to block. We changed the Probe to one of the monitoring ports we exposed and that fixed the issue.